Flutter unexpected behavior after logout and login again
I am facing some issues in my flutter project. I use firebase for login and get the following unexpected behavior.

Login with a user -> right after login the user is redirected to the main screen
I logout again
I login with the same user or another user again -> I expect the user to be redirected to the main screen again
But: The login screen is still visible
I close the app and reopen it (or refresh it in vs code)
The main screen is visible now

The case that the login screen is still visible after login again (after the logout) is not the expected behavior. This only happens if I was logged in right bevor the login. If I login after the app has been restarted the behavior is as expected and the user is redirected to the main screen.
Main.dart
import 'package:davkursmanager/providers/userdata_provider.dart';
import 'package:davkursmanager/screens/events/event_details.dart';
import 'package:davkursmanager/screens/login/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:davkursmanager/screens/mainscreen/main_screen.dart';
import 'package:davkursmanager/screens/mainscreen/not_activated.dart';
import 'package:davkursmanager/theme.dart';
import 'package:davkursmanager/widgets/constants/loading.dart';
import 'package:firebase_app_check/firebase_app_check.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await dotenv.load();

  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
  );

  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Constructs a [MyApp]
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: _router,
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('de', 'DE')],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'testapp',
      theme: getThemeData(),
    );
  }
}

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

/// The route configuration.
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: <RouteBase>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Loading();
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Consumer(
                builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? child) {
                  final userProfileAsync = ref.watch(userProfileProvider);
                  return userProfileAsync.when(
                    data: (userData) {
                      if (userData != null) {
                        //check if user has already been activated
                        bool accountActivated = userData.accountActivated;
                        return accountActivated
                            ? const MainScreen()
                            : const AccountNotActivatedScreen();
                      } else {
                        //other events
                        return Center(
                          child: Loading(),
                        );
                      }
                    },
                    loading: () => Scaffold(body: Loading()),
                    error: (error, stackTrace) {
                      return const Text(
                          'Fehler beim Abrufen der Benutzerdaten');
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return const LoginScreen();
            }
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
);


This is my provider I use for user data. Maybe there is something wrong?
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:davkursmanager/models/user/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

//provider to get profile data
//stream provider gets data every time the profile is loaded
final userProfileProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<UserData?>((ref) {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  final currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
  if (currentUser != null) {
    final userDocRef = _firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid);

    return userDocRef.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        final userData = snapshot.data();
        return UserData(
          userData?['email'],
          userData?['firstName'],
          userData?['lastName'],
          userData?['membershipNumber'],
          userData?['accountActivated'],
          userData?['isAdmin'],
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  }

  return Stream.value(null);
});


This is the method I use for login:
Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      BuildContext context, String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (context.mounted) {
        if (e.code == "wrong-password") {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              content: Text("Falsches Passwort"),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 7),
            ),
          );
        } else if (e.code == "user-not-found") {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              content: Text("Benutzer nicht gefunden"),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 7),
            ),
          );
        } else if (e.code == "invalid-credential") {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              content: Text("Bitte überprüfe deine Zugangsdaten"),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 7),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          //all other errors
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              content: Text("Ein unerwarteter Fehler ist aufgetreten"),
              duration: Duration(seconds: 7),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }


and this is the section where the user can logout:
TextButton(
     onPressed: () async {
     try {
        await _auth.signOut().then((res) {
               Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,MaterialPageRoute(
                       builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()),(route) => true,
                                );
                       ref.invalidate(userProfileProvider);
               });
         } catch (e) {
           rethrow;
     }
},
child: Text("Logout", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge!.copyWith(fontSize: 20,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),

